# Can't write "top -b" output to file

Tags: linux, awk

I want to capture the output from `top` along with a timestamp, so I execute this:

```
top -b | awk '/dockerd/ {print strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S"), $0}'
```

This prints out the following:

```
2017-05-11-18:54:18  2569 root 20 0  624m  41m  28m S  0.0  4.2   0:07.32 dockerd
2017-05-11-18:54:21  2569 root 20 0  624m  41m  28m S  0.0  4.2   0:07.32 dockerd
2017-05-11-18:54:24  2569 root 20 0  624m  41m  28m S  0.0  4.2   0:07.32 dockerd
```

All good, except when I attempt to redirect the output to a file like this:

```
sudo top -b |
awk '/dockerd/ {print strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S"), $0}' >> top.txt 2>&1
```

`top.txt` is always empty. Why can't I get the output written into the file?

Comment: `top -b` stays on the terminal window. It never exits from this command to pass it to the pipe.

Comment: My guess is it is writing to the file, but it's just being buffered before writing to disk.  If you wait long enough, it should write a 4 KB chunk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is writing to the file, but awk is buffering the data from the pipe.  I can tell you're running gawk, so [one of many solutions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/83853/227698) in this case is to add `system("")`:

```
top -b |
awk '/wget/ {print strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S"), $0; system("")}' >top.txt 2>&1
```

If you were running `mawk`, you could provide `-Winteractive` to the awk command.

A more [general-purpose solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/25378/227698) could be to pipe to `stdbuf`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try redirecting the output of one iteration, then loop it, maybe something like this:

```
while :; do top -n 1 -b >> top.txt; sleep 1; done
```

Comment: Cool solution @Jens, I didn't know that was possible.

Comment: It gets even cooler: all control constructs take a *list*, so they can be made from several pipes; the exit status of the last pipe then determines the truth value: `if cmd1|cmd2; cmdA|cmdB; then ...; fi`. Here `cmdB` is what the `if` evaluates.

Comment: this is good to know,  I'm having a difficult time contriving a practical use case for this, however :-)

Answer (score 1):

The following line seems to work for me.

```
top -b | stdbuf -o 0 awk '/wget/ {print strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S"), $0}' >> top.txt
```

The problem is that `awk` (in my case `gawk`) was in fact buffering the output (confirmed by using `strace` to verify). So `stdbuf` worked to unbuffer the output. Note, however, that `stdbuf` doesn't work for all commands (see `stdbuf(1)` IE `man stdbuf`)